# How do I correct a Rails cron.log error showing it can't find bundler 2.4.3 when I do have bundler 2.4.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

Newbie, I'm trying to run a first time cron job in Rails 7 with whenever gem. I get the following error in the cron.log:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.4.3) required by your /Users/myname/mysite/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.4.3`
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I have this sample.rake:

```
namespace :sample do
  desc "saying hi to cron"
  task test: :developement do
    puts 'hi cron'
  end

end
```

And this schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "log/cron.log"

 every 1.minute do
  rake 'sample:test'
 end
```

gem list | grep bundle
bundler (2.4.3)

bundler -v
Bundler version 2.4.3

I have run 'bundle update --bundler` but it does nothing.
I have updated Homebrew, it does nothing.
any help?

Comment: Are you sure you have it for your system Ruby? The `cron` environment can be different than you expect if you have something like `rbenv` involved.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean @tadman